# Batch: Set the path for a file created by batch

Tags: file, batch-file, random, cmd

I'm trying to create a small program which will create a .txt file on the c-drive it should add the text of %random% to it, but how can i set the path?

Comment: `echo %random% >c:\path\file.txt` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
type %random% > c:\create.txt
```

-> This adds the content of %random% to your text file create.txt.
-> If you already know the path of %random%, you can set it as an environment variable.
-> Else, echo command can be used.